# Ajax call fires success event but returns 201 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Ajax on a Laravel project and I have a button that fires a function with two status error and success. but on both of them the success message returns.

Controller:

```
if ($user->balance < $total_paid) {
return response()->json(['responseText' => 'error'], 201);
} else {
return response()->json(['responseText' => 'success!'], 200);
}
```

Ajax function in the frontend:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function pay_with_ewallet()    { 
            $.ajax({
              url: "{!!URL::route('pay_with_ewallet')!!}",
              type: "post",
              data: {
                'OrderShipAddress':$('input[name=OrderShipAddress]').val(), 
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'OrderEmail':$('input[name=OrderEmail]').val(),
                'city_id':$('select[name=city_id] :selected').val(),
                'OrderPhone':$('input[name=OrderPhone]').val(),
                'shipping_cost': @if (isset( $shipping_total )) {{ $shipping_total  }} @endif ,
                'order_total':@if (isset( $final_total )) {{ $final_total  }} @endif,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (response == 'success') 
                        $("#myElem").show();
                        setTimeout(function() { $("#myElem").hide(); }, 10000);
                    else 
                        $("#myerror").show();
                        setTimeout(function() { $("#myerror").hide(); }, 10000);
                }​
            });
        }
    </script>
```

and the button:

```
<button href="" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="pay_with_ewallet-btn {{ $user->id }}" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" onclick="pay_with_ewallet('pay_with_ewallet{{ $user->id }}')">{{ trans('interface.pay_with_e_wallet') }}</button>
```

I tried whatever I can and a lot of research on the internet but was useless.

Comment: `201` is not an error case.

Comment: As said, 201 is not an error, and jQuery will still accept it as a `success`. In the context of your code a 403 FORBIDDEN, or even just 400 BAD REQUEST would seem more appropriate - as long as you give a more descrptive response than `'error'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`201` is an existing HTTP CODE response and means `created` and a fulfilled request. So for Ajax is a success. Try to use different numbers, out of standars (100-505).

https://httpstatuses.com/201